# Play framework - add header before redirection

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am trying to add a new header to the original request, and then redirect it to a new URL.

```
return redirect("http://newurl.com/hello").withHeader("header", "value");
```

The above redirects the original request without adding the new header value.

Is this possible using `redirects`? If so, how? If not, will I have to create a new request based on the original request first?

Comment: I read the source for `redirect` and `withHeader` and it looks like your code should work. What version of Play are you using? What actual headers do you get on the response? I expect the new header to be on the 303 response not on the response from `http://newurl.com/hello`.

Comment: Using Play 2.6. Yes, the header is found on the 303 response. I am trying to add it to the original request. Is this possible?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need to add a header to the original request before doing a redirect?

Comment: I'm a bit confused too. If you want a header on the "original request" then you need to modify whichever client is  connecting to Play. Play only sends responses, not requests.

Comment: So I'm gathering that it is not possible to modify the original request headers before redirection? 

I ideally want to modify the original request with the new headers and forward it to a new service (which requires my modifications as well), to process the request.

Comment: So, what you want is to create a redirect **result** that also has the headers of the original **request**, is that right?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to read a request from the client, then have the server create a request and send it to a new service, then return the result to the client. Take a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought too. I was hoping for a shorter approach but it seems this is the only way. Thanks anyway.